# Trying to organize result from array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to organize the output from array in c#

But below script is not working

```
using System;

namespace text.cs
{
    class Exec
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            var variations_array = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            ArrayList item_array = new ArrayList();

            foreach (var entry in item_array)
            {
                Console.Write ("[{0},]"entry);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

> [3456,2323,34345,4566,23234]

I don't want to enclose double quotes for each item and this should be stored into a variable

In python I would do like this

```
print array
```

I am new to c#. How to get this output working (storing an output from array to a variable in above organized way)?

Comment: You never put anything into your `item_array`. How Should it match your expected output?

Comment: You should be able to use `string.Join` to accomplish this without a loop, but first you really shouldn't be using `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to add something to your array List

```
ArrayList item_array = new ArrayList();
item_array.Add("3456");
item_array.Add("2323");
item_array.Add("34345");
item_array.Add("4566");
item_array.Add("23234");

//the easiest way to show your output is by string.join but that doesn't take array list directly, so we need to cast to particular datatype

var str = "[" + String.Join(",", item_array.Cast<string>().ToList()) + "]";
Console.Write(str);

str would be [3456,2323,34345,4566,23234]
```

I would strongly recommend to use a Strongly typed List , List of string as in your case

Comment: You know you can just add the `int` values directly like `item_array.Add(3456);`.

Comment: you don't need to turn it into a list. `join` takes an `IEnumerable<string>` as it's second argument, so the `cast<string>`is sufficient

Comment: Also you're only going to be able to cast to `int`.  Casting to `string` would throw, instead you could just cast to `object` then you don't have to worry about what might be in the `ArraryList`.

Comment: @juharr. OP wanted to should be stored into a variable, that's why I didn't added directly

Comment: @Pankaj I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @juharr, read this line in question. #i dont want to enclose double quotes for each item and this should be stored into a variable

Comment: @Pankaj I believe the variable they are talking about is the `string` they want to create to represent the values in the array.  That has nothing to do with storing the values into a variable before adding them to the array, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @juharr, I agree and I guess I interpreted it wrong, Edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

If you used a type collection instead of ArrayList you could use the join static method on the String class

```
var str = "[" + System.String.Join(",",item_array) + "]";
Console.Write(str);
```

the output of that will be

```
[3456,2323,34345,4566,23234]
```

which if I understood the question correctly is what you want
However since ArrayList is not typed you would need to use either an array of string or a `List<string>` instead

It will work with any `IEnumerable<T>` not just those mentioned above. So if your choice of `ArrayList` is a result of working with legacy code you can convert it into an IEnumerable and then the code would look like this

```
var enumerable = item_array.Cast<string>();
var str = "[" + System.String.Join(",",enumerable) + "]";
Console.Write(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Join` is what you're looking for. But first of all, you should not be using an `ArrayList` but rather a generic list such as `List<T>`

Then you'd be able to do this :

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", yourList));
```

Also, you can check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5bx6xee.aspx) to see the benefits of using generic collections over `ArrayList`